# Set two different values/results with CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have these two CASE statements in a much larger query -

```
CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2017' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END DNR2017,
CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2018' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END DNR2018
```

The problem I'm running into is that if it equals 2017, then both DNR2017 and DNR2018 need to be set to 'YES'.  As it is right now, in the cases where the date is in 2017, it's setting DNR2017 to YES, but leaving DNR2018 as NO.  Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From you logic I would use `TO_NUMBER` function.

```
(CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY')) <= 2017 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as DNR2017,
(CASE WHEN TO_NUMBER(to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY')) <= 2018 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as DNR2018
```

**EDIT**

Thank @Alex Poole point out you can also use `extract` to get year number.

```
(CASE WHEN extract(year from tm.DNRDATE) = 2017 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as DNR2017,
(CASE WHEN extract(year from tm.DNRDATE) BETWEEN 2017 AND 2018 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as DNR2018
```

Comment: Although Gordon's answer works, I like this one a little better because the table from which I'm pulling data may have 2016 data added to it as well and that would cover me in all cases.  Thank you.

Comment: This will match data from 2016 and before too though; not clear if that's desirable... (You can also `extract(year from tm.DNRDATE)`, which I think is a bit clearer, but YMMV...)

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks `extract` will be more elegant than `TO_NUMBER`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in`:

```
(CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') = '2017' THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as DNR2017,
(CASE WHEN to_char(tm.DNRDATE,'YYYY') IN ('2017', '2018') THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END) as DNR2018
```